# Files cached even though Chrome cache has been disabled

Tags: php, caching, browser, xampp, laravel-7

I am using Laravel 7 and I am attempting to test a changed JS file but the file isn't updating on my local XAMPP server its showing the old changes even though I have saved the JS file. I have tried going to F12 > Network > Disable Cache and I have added  LoadModule cache_module modules/mod_cache.so to my httpd.conf file in my local XAMPP server.

All of the files have a ?version=30 extension added to combat cache but this isn't working anymore.

I have also tried loading in a different browser and pressing shift + f5.

Is there something I'm missing. Thanks.

Comment: do u tried changing ?version=30 to ?version=31 after saving js file ?

Comment: Yeah quite a few changes. That was just an example. I cant find anything on what could be causing this.

Comment: ok. try with change name of js file >> then view page source if new named file is loaded or not ...

Comment: The JS is definitely loaded but changing the name didn't help either.